# ReactJS Calling a JSON API

Tags: json, reactjs

In my JSON file I have a few layers of data that I would like to call from. My JSON data, as shown in my `getInitState` is organized as `{forthem:[{articles:[]}]}`. You can also view my data at https://emjayweb.github.io/portfolio/scripts/snippets.json.

The first function, where I'm using variable `fakeit` works as expected. However, the second function, where I'm calling `makeit` to access my `articles` data does not work. I get a `Cannot read map of undefined` error.

I have included my full code below for review.

```
getInitialState:function(){
    return {forname: '', forsym: '', fortitle: '', fulldata: {forthem:[ {articles: [] } ]}  }
},

componentDidMount:function(){
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON('https://emjayweb.github.io/portfolio/scripts/snippets.json', function(snowden){
        self.setState({fulldata: snowden});
    });
},

render:function(){        
    return (<div id="madeforlist">
        <ul>
            {this.state.fulldata.forthem.map(function(fakeit, i){
                return <li key={i}>
                            <i className="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span id="forname">{fakeit.therefore}</span>
                            <span className="pull-right">{fakeit.theresym}</span>
                        </li>})}
            <ul>
            {this.state.fulldata.forthem.articles.map(function(makeit, o){
                return <li key={o}>{makeit.article}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        </ul>    
    </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forthem` is an array so literally you need to pass an index to get the array articles

try `this.state.fulldata.forthem[0].articles.map()`

```
this.state.fulldata.forthem.map(function(fakeit,i){

   fakeit.articles.map(function(article,j){

   })   
})
```

Comment: So this works. However, I seem only to be able to call [0]. I get an `article of undefined` error if I replace this with [1].

Answer (score 1):

`Cannot read map of undefined` error is cause of the `this.state.fulldata.forthem.articles.map()` the `articles` is `undefined`.

And I wonder if GitHub.io support cross-domain? If not, this code cannot be working because getJSON cannot get the data from your gist.

Comment: I am able to make API calls from my Github. The only problem is, as you mentioned, the `articles` is undefined. And I am not sure how to define it in React using the map function. EDIT: Got it!